# encrypt-decrypt single block with AES and Crypto++

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++, block-cipher

I need to encrypt single block of AES. I cant use any modes like CBC and other. Every example what i have seen use streaming modes.

EDIT:
ok, i did it in the next manner, but i really dislike this try.

```
void dec(const byte *key, const byte* xblock, const byte *cipher, byte *plain) {
    AESDecryption d;

    try {
        const NameValuePairs &nvp = MakeParameters("", 0);
        d.UncheckedSetKey(key, 16, nvp);
        d.ProcessAndXorBlock(cipher, xblock, plain);
    }
    catch(...) {}
}
```

Comment: You want [ECB mode](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_e_c_b___mode.html).

Comment: @GregS, no)) I want to do mode by myself, i need to encode one block by AES primitive.

Comment: That is what ECB mode means!! It is just encrypting one block using the AES primitive.

Comment: @GregS No, it isn't. ECB mode may accept multiple blocks, but the encryption of the blocks does not depend on any of the other blocks. And it may be insecure if the data in any of the blocks is related.

Answer (score 6):

AES in ECB mode is identical to single block encryption, except that you can feed it multiple blocks.

If you've got only CBC mode encryption available you can use the first block of a CBC encrypt using a (block sized) IV containing bytes all valued zero. The same goes for counter (CTR) mode encryption and a nonce containing bytes all valued zero (the counter only increases after the first block encrypt).

Crypto++ seems to be a higher level Crypto API, so it is better not to directly call the AES implementation directly.

Comment: It this answer acceptable for you, Yola, if not please indicate what is missing. Please accept answers if possible, otherwise they are left open and on the unanswered questions stack.