# Example of encrypting one AES block needed

Tags: c++, aes, crypto++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [encrypt-decrypt single block with AES and Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082432/encrypt-decrypt-single-block-with-aes-and-crypto)

I have a homework that involves implementing two operation modes of AES, but the problem is that I don't know how to encrypt a single AES block. As in, I don't know how to use Crypto++'s implementation of AES in isolation. Everywhere I looked I could only find code snippets that use the library's operation modes, and even though I know that's how it's supposed to be used, I would like to actually do it myself for the assignment. Can anyone please help with some C++ code example?

Comment: posted an answer over there as well, as the answer (by GregS) was only available in a comment

Comment: Feel free to vote the answer up if it solves the question for you :)